# php: Echo "alt tag" contents to "title tag"

Tags: php, jquery, html, tags, alt

Images in PHP files have an "alt" tag, but I need to duplicate its content to "title" tag.  So the code automatically reads the page when it loads, and adds the new "title" tag beside the "alt" tag, whether using PHP, jQuery, JavaScript..

Example:

```
<img border="0" src="../../../../images/divider.jpg" alt="description of image" width="410" height="15">
```

Output:

```
<img border="0" src="../../../../images/divider.jpg" alt="description of image" title="description of image" width="410" height="15">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you can search `<img>` tags, and add this title attribute:

```
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (let i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
  if (!imgs[i].title) // if title is not defined
      imgs[i].title = imgs[i].alt;
}
```

Using jQuery, you can use find images `$('img')` and loop using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('img').each(function(img) {
  if (!this.title)
    this.title = this.alt;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried it but couldn't get it to work.. can you please make a demo at https://jsfiddle.net/ or something?

Comment: @Mike see https://jsfiddle.net/u3hfkxg9/ You should inspect the image tag to see the title attribute.

Comment: Or https://jsfiddle.net/u3hfkxg9/1/ with jQuery, and https://jsfiddle.net/u3hfkxg9/2/ using DOMReady.

Comment: It worked, thanks..  But why when I view source of the page it doesn't show the new tag?

Comment: The source shows you the HTML generated by the server. Using JavaScript, the DOM is updated on the client side. So, it can be only viewed on the browser inspector.

Comment: is it possible to do it server-side?